# group by one column while selecting multiplet columns [laravel]

Tags: php, jquery, sql, database, laravel-5

I have this query which works fine, but I want to select a column without putting it in GroupBy  how can i do it

My Query

```
$navigation_data_unassigned = DB::table('ccctadm.Shipment')->select('ccctadm.documentruleset.status','rulesetname', 'icon', DB::raw('COUNT(*) As Total'))->join('ccctadm.documentruleset', function ($join) {
   $join->on('ccctadm.Shipment.customergroupcode', '=', 'ccctadm.documentruleset.customergroupcode')->on('ccctadm.Shipment.shipmentcategory', '=', 'ccctadm.documentruleset.shipmentcategory')->on('ccctadm.Shipment.status', '=', 'ccctadm.documentruleset.status');
})->whereNotIn('ccctadm.Shipment.id', function ($query) {
        $query->select('shipmentid')->from('ccctadm.shipassign');
})->Where('shipment_cycle', '!=', 'closed')->groupBy('rulesetname', 'icon')->get();
```

The following query will return

```
 rulesetname    icon          total 
 ---------------------------------------
 release        fdsdsf.png      20     
 blank          fdsdsf.png      20     
 restricted     fdsdsf.png      20
```

I want to add more column

```
    rulesetname      icon       status         total   
     ---------------------------------------------------
     release        fdsdsf.png   shipped         20     
     blank          fdsdsf.png   pending         20     
     restricted     fdsdsf.png   shipped         20
```

so I want to select status column and return its data without adding it in groupby

Comment: Provide some more details. you only want to select one column ? or whats you want ?

Comment: I have added more explanation for the wanted result

Comment: I want to select status  column without  adding it in groupBy, because if i do I will get different results

Answer (score 0):

Just delete/skip your GroupBy query

```
Where('shipment_cycle', '!=', 'closed')->groupBy('rulesetname', 'icon')->get();
```

become this one

```
Where('shipment_cycle', '!=', 'closed')->get();
```

Comment: I have aggravated function COUNT(*) As Total, Also I want to group the results or  use distinct   if possible